# How to set only certain characters to be inputted into an entry widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am very new to Python and tkinter and I am making a GUI calculator at the moment I have everything set up and working but you can type letters into the entry via clicking on it or pressing off my keyboard as I have a `key.char` bind

```
def keyboard(press):
    entry.insert(END, key.char)
```

And I am wondering if there is a way I can disable the user from being able to press letters like <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd> etc. and only my buttons list which is just <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>AC</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `validate` attribute for the `entry widget`this an example to demonstrate that. I created a `function`  named `Only_Integer(S)` and parse the characters i want the `entry` to accept as a `List`. So if the character you entered in the `entry widget` is not an `integer` should `return False`( *it will not accept*).

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def sum():
    add = e1.get()+ e2.get()
    print(add)

def Only_Integer(S):
    if S in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
        return True                                                       
     return False

vcmd = (root.register(Only_Integer), '%S')

e1 = Entry(root, validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)
e1.pack()

e2 = Entry(validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)
e2.pack()

b = Button(root, text="calculate", command=sum)
b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is vcmd mean something because i saw another post like this and they used vcmd as well and im wondering if its just a common variable name like callback or does it mean something more

Comment: it just `variable`name  you can name variable any name you want

Comment: i was looking over and playing around with this code and when i changed the %S it no longer worked could you explain or send me somewhere that could explain what the %S does. Also thank you so much this code is exactly what i needed

Comment: and why does it it brake my AC and = button because when i implement this everything works fine but my = button stops working and my AC button stops working so when you press = it does nothing no error in shell just nothing happens and = does nothing does this code override that?

Comment: the `S` is an `args` for the the function you can change it to any name you want  and can check that one one functions and also to make `=` and `AC` to work add it to the list  `..., '8', '9',"="`

Comment: i don't understand by what you mean add it to the list.

Comment: my list is currently if S in ["(",")","del","AC","7","8","9","*","4","5","6","-","1","2","3","+","0",".","=","/"]:

Comment: and i added AC afterwards to give it a function name but how do you add it into the list i dont get it